# Stack Exchange pages don't print?

Tags: support

I tried saving a genealogy discussion and the Stack Exchange seems to allow only one page to be printed. I know there would be more than one page. I don't see a Print Icon either. Am I missing something?

Comment: Various solutions in the answers here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=print

Answer (score 3):

I just printed one of my recent questions ([Reading remarks from Royal Hospital, Chelsea record from early 19th century?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/reading-remarks-from-royal-hospital-chelsea-record-from-early-19th-century)) which has a question ID of 15167 using StackPrinter:

http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=15167&service=genealogy.stackexchange

I learned how to do this at [Can I print a single answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128703/can-i-print-a-single-answer) (which also tells you how you can print just a single answer).